# Why does inelastic X-ray scattering probe the longitudinal dielectric function as opposed to the transverse dielectric function?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

Light is a transverse wave. Therefore, light in the optical range (i.e. visible light) couples to transverse collective excitations of a material when measuring the optical conductivity for instance. Likewise, X-rays are also transverse waves, but somehow couple to longitudinal collective excitations of a material.

I understand that it is because X-ray photons couple to the electron density as detailed in this [paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/0953-8984/13/34/304), but what I am looking for is a plausible intuitive explanation with some physical insight as to why this might be so.

(Sorry if you can't view the paper from the publisher without incurring a fee, but I couldn't find it anywhere else. I think the question is clear enough without the link, though.)

Comment: The waves are transverse, but depending on their polarization when they are incident on the material (S vs P polarization), can have a component normal to the interface of the medium.  That component can excite longitudinal waves.

Comment: Even at normal incidence, where the polarization is parallel to the interface, one still excites longitudinal waves.